# configure proguard to optimize library projects (and not main project)

Tags: android, ant, amazon-web-services, proguard, library-project

My app has 2 projects:

- A library project with everything (app-abstract.jar)
- The small launchable project, that runs it, and includes a third party library

This way I can have several launchable projects for the different versions of the app (Google Play/Amazon/Tablets...)

Problem:

One of my small launchable projects, specifically for Amazon, has a libary "in-app-purchasing.jar", barely 80kb, that requires to **turn off all proguard optimizations**,

So I wonder **how can I configure proguard, if possible at all, to make the optimizations on the first project only**

... as that project is included as a big LIBRARY JAR I feel this has to be easy to do, probably manipulating the ant scripts, because I mean, at the end the app has 2 clearly defined pieces:

- app.jar, 3mb
- amazon in-app-billing.jar 80kb

Maybe is it possible to run proguard two times, one on every jar?

Comment: You can consider using gradle as build tool: it has "product flavor" built-in feature and it seems that's precilely what you need.

Comment: The product flavour feature of gradle is in fact what I have implemented with my structure. But gradle or not, the problem would be the same: the input pieces to proguard INSIDE ONE FLAVOUR have to be obfuscated separately

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the Amazon library with these lines in proguard-project.txt for the application project:

```
-keep class com.amazon.inapp.** { *; }
```

This should be sufficient for Amazon, while still allowing other code to be optimized and obfuscated.

Comment: unfortunately with Amazon In-App billing, they also require to turn off optimizations as stated https://developer.amazon.com/post/TxHZ4VD3PRBCAV/Code-Obfuscation-for-the-Amazon-In-App-Purchasing-API.html << there. If you don't do it, Proguard crashes with a fatal error :)